# Speed up matrix product via precomputations

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm working on a problem where a matrix has to be iteratively computed a very large number of times. The necessary matrix multiplication takes the form

```
t(X) %*% ( ( X %*% W %*% t(X) * mu0 ) * mu1 )
```

where `X` is `N x P` and `W` is a **symmetric** `P x P` matrix. `mu0` and `mu1` are `N x 1` vectors that are cheap to compute and enter the respective products element-wise.

Unfortunately, `N` may be quite large, which leads to an immense computational demand due to `X %*% W %*% t(X)` being `N x N`. I was wondering whether there are any strategies or computational tricks, for instance based on matrix decompositions, that could be used to speed up computations here. In every iteration, `mu0` and `mu1` change, but `X` and `W` are fixed, so any precomputations including those matrices will work.

**BENCHMARKING**

The fastest approach that I could think of so far is to do some obvious precomputations:

```
# fake data
N   = 2500
P   = 10
X   = matrix(rnorm(N*P), N, P)
W   = matrix(rnorm(P*P), P, P)
mu0 = rnorm(N)
mu1 = rnorm(N)

# precomputations
tX  = t(X)
XWX = X %*% W %*% t(X)

# functions
f_raw      = function(X, W, mu0, mu1){t(X) %*% ( ( X %*% W %*% t(X) * mu0 ) * mu1 )}
f_precomp  = function(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1){tX %*% ( ( XWX * mu0 ) * mu1 )}


# benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f_raw(X, W, mu0, mu1), 
                               f_precomp(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1))


Unit: milliseconds
                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        f_raw(X, W, mu0, mu1) 283.5918 286.5080 299.4621 289.5151 302.9726 355.4271   100
 f_precomp(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1) 167.4169 168.7336 180.6468 171.0852 197.7475 263.8090   100
```

Comment: You can explore using RCPP package to do these kind of computations in C++.

Comment: Sure, that's a natural next step, but I was wondering whether there's something more "structural" to be gained here before using more efficient languages.

Comment: As matrix multiplication is associative, you might be able to reduce the size of an intermediate rsult by adding parentheses around one multiplication.

Comment: If you have gpu on your machine try `torch` library or `tensorflow`

Comment: @tushaR Using Rcpp won't help for most matrix algebra. R already passes the calculations to the BLAS. Linking R with an optimized BLAS might be a better option. (I also suspect applying some algebra before computing anything would be the way to go here. But I can't help with that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example data and attempt:

```
# fake data
N   = 2500
P   = 10
X   = matrix(rnorm(N*P), N, P)
W   = matrix(rnorm(P*P), P, P)
mu0 = rnorm(N)
mu1 = rnorm(N)

# precomputations
tX  = t(X)
XWX = X %*% W %*% t(X)

# functions
f_raw      = function(X, W, mu0, mu1){t(X) %*% ( ( X %*% W %*% t(X) * mu0 ) * mu1 )}
f_precomp  = function(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1){tX %*% ( ( XWX * mu0 ) * mu1 )}
```

A better idea is to pre-compute

```
WX <- tcrossprod(W, X)
```

Then

```
f_better <- function (X, mu0, mu1, WX) crossprod(X, (mu0 * mu1) * X) %*% WX
```

Benchmark on my laptop:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f_raw(X, W, mu0, mu1), 
                               f_precomp(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1),
                               f_better(X, mu0, mu1, WX))
#Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr        min         lq      mean     median
#        f_raw(X, W, mu0, mu1) 236.926979 238.984573 243.86319 242.212716
# f_precomp(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1) 151.190689 152.612059 156.25277 155.646093
#    f_better(X, mu0, mu1, WX)   1.113031   1.126434   1.17974   1.138207
#         uq        max neval
# 244.721163 270.477737   100
# 157.970378 182.935082   100
#   1.146352   5.130876   100
```

To verify correctness:

```
ans_raw <- f_raw(X, W, mu0, mu1)
ans_precomp <- f_precomp(XWX, tX, mu0, mu1)
ans_better <- f_better(X, mu0, mu1, WX)

all.equal(ans_raw, ans_precomp)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(ans_raw, ans_better)
# [1] TRUE
```

I don't know if `mu0` and `mu1` are guaranteed to be non-negative in your real application. If so, the following is 2x faster:

```
f_fastest <- function (X, mu0, mu1, WX) crossprod(sqrt(mu0 * mu1) * X) %*% WX
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, thanks! Unfortunately both vectors are real valued, but the improvement of the first version is already much appreciated!

Comment: Nice proposal of using `crossprod` and `tcrossprod`, +1!

Comment: Great approach as always!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Great to see you as well.